# SQL: Select table if a column has a given value

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am new to SQL and programming in general, this could be an easy question, or it may not be, I have not clue. I just know I have not been able to find a straightforward answer. I have an excel file with a bunch of different data sheets. Each data sheet has the same data, just for different occurances. I want to be able to associate certain readings with a given value of the subject. (i.e. I want to be able to return all paces recorded during a race if the person is under 24 years old)  In this situation, the paces would be recorded every minutes during a 2 hour race. That would be in a column pace, age would be in another column age. There will be a data sheet for every subject. I ultimately would like to find the average pace of all people in different age ranges (24 and under etc.) I can combine the columns with the UNION command. I am working with SQL in R. What I have looks like this:

`sqlQuery(Race, paste("SELECT [PACE] FROM [Bill] UNION [STEVE]"))`

I understand the WHERE clause to return rows where the given value is present. My dilemma is I have enough data it would be very time consuming to input the age for every row so that I can query the rows.

Is it possible for me to create code that asks something like "***return me all table where age is less than 24?***"

Comment: You need this data to be in one table, where the person name is a column in the table (and not the name of the table itself)

Comment: How does R fit into the equation here? You sql query does not appear to be valid syntax either. The `union` and `union all` operators need full fledged select queries to work. Perhaps something like `select [pace] from [bill] union select [pace] from [steve]`. I also don't see an age column in your select query...

Comment: You actually probably need two tables: in the first table the record is people, and there is the name and the age.  In the second table is the name of the person and the pace measurement.

Comment: This just an example similar to one a project that I am working on, the information of the project is confidential. It is a large data set with lots of analysis to be done on it. I want to use SQL to manipulate the different data sheets (which brought into R as tables). R can use sql with the RODBC package. I figured it would be easier to manipulate with sql, and then analyze the data in R, if I were to use R itself, I would have a huge table with lots of columns, all of which will have very similar names (most for the same fields that need to be kept together.)

Comment: sqlQuery is the command in R that lets a person take a query of the imported data. Each occurance is set up as a different data sheet in excel (imported as individual tables with name last_name_4_5_11$ etc.) Each table contains certain values lets call them "C" recorded every 15 minutes. There different values for the individuals that are Independent variables that are unique to the person and never change, I will call them "H" and "B". I want to be able to find which people have certain conditions (<20 for "B") and then find the measures of central tendancy of "C"....

Comment: for all individuals that satisfy the requirement for "B", the goal is to find correlations between "B" and "C" or "H" and "C" This is easily done in R. However, when I use the WHERE clause, it returns only values of the column in the row where "B" satisfies the requirement. I want to be able to extract all of "C" where the entry for "B" is satisfied. "C" has about 50 entries, with the characteristic "B" has one entry. @antlersoft1 Is that more clear?

Answer (score 3):

I'd strongly advise against putting each data sheet into its own table - just add a column DATA_SHEET to your table to differentiate between occurences.
That said, I'd probably go one step further and use these tables (assuming one data sheet represents one race):

```
PERSON
------
PK
Name
Age (better: Date of birth, since age changes over time)
Gender
...

RACE
----
PK
Name
Start date
...

PACE
----
PERSON_FK -- foreign key to PERSON table
RACE_FK -- foreign key to race table
PACE
...
```

This way, to get all paces of people younger than 24 for a given race:

```
select race.name race_name, person.name person_name, pace.pace 
from person, race, pace
where person.pk = pace.person_fk
and race.pk = pace.race_fk
and person.age < 24
```

Comment: What is a foreign key? And how would I set one up?

Comment: @Lucas A foreign key is a cross-table reference. By adding a foreign key on race_fk in this example, you tell the database that this race_fk "points" to a row in the Race table, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key for further reading.

Answer (score 0):

Try `avg()` function of sql server and with where condition `where ageCol < 24`

Comment: is there a way for me to pinpoint a specific entry in the WHERE clause to use all the values of a column in that table when Age is less than 24? The WHERE command returns only a corresponding pace value to the entry that has age, however there is one entry for age and many entries for pace.

Answer (score 0):

```
sqlQuery(Race, paste("SELECT [PACE], AVG(PACE) FROM [Bill] UNION [STEVE] WHERE columnName["age"] < 24"))
```

I'm not a master in SQL-server/T-SQL and I have no experience developing R, but in SQL the syntax is not so different from this.

But you could separate the queries like this (I have no clue if the syntax is good):

```
sqlQuery(Race, paste("SELECT [PACE] FROM [Bill] UNION [STEVE] WHERE [PACE].age < 24"))
```

then:

```
sqlQuery(Race, paste("SELECT AVG([PACE].age) FROM [Bill] UNION [STEVE]"))
```

Answer (score 0):

The question:

> Blockquote "return me all table where age is less than 24?"

Implies that you would have more than one table with a column called age.  If the age applies to the runner I would suggest reviewing your schema.  You should have an entity named something like:

Person
or
Runner
or
Participant

That has a column age.  The trick would then be to simply move all your data into that table.  Then a simple

SELECT
   *
FROM
   Person
WHERE
   age < 24

Would return all the data you're looking for.

I think where this is getting confusing is the concept of a datasheet in excel vs. a table in SQL.  Your data sheets sound like they're instances of a participant with various additional data.  Instead of creating a table for each data sheet you should create a schema that fits all of your data and then fill it with each instance from your data.

Take a look here for a reference to schema design:

[How to design this RDBMS schema?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3131551/how-to-design-this-rdbms-schema)